# Set closed under quotients and remainders

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Suppose that an infinite set $S= {0,1,2,4,8,...}$ of integers written in monotonically increasing order (that is, all other members are integers greater than 8) has the property that Euclidean division of any integer $a$ in $S$ by any integer $b\ne0$ in $S$ (regardless of whether $a>b$) gives quotient $q$ and remainder $r$ also in $S$. That is, $S$ is closed under Euclidean division. Obviously, $S$ could then be ${0,1,2,4,8,16,...}$, but is it possible to prove that there are no other infinite sets $S=0,1,2,4,8,...$ satisfying the closure property?

Comment: No, because $0,1,3,9,27,\ldots$ satisfy that property.

Comment: By the way, what is $1$ euclidean-divided by $0$?

Comment: Possibly should specify $b\ne0$. Also I believe he means that the first five terms of $S$ must be as specified.

Comment: Thanks, I cleared that up.

Comment: I found a relevant paper: Sets Closed under the Division Algorithm, Stanton 2015. That should cover it.